# Is there a term for continued fractions of the form $[b; b, b, b \dots ]$?

Tags: terminology, continued-fractions

We denote the continued fraction
$$a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{\ddots}}}$$
in shorthand as $[a_0;a_1,a_2 \dots]$  or as $[a_0;a_1,a_2 \dots a_n]$ if it is finitely nested. I would like to know if there is a term for continued fractions of the form $[a;a,a\dots]$ and/or $[0;a,a\dots]$ where the constants are all equal (either finitely or infinitely nested.)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction

Comment: For positional systems this is called [repdigit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit) (for "repeated digit"), but I haven't seen it used on continued fractions. $[1;1,1 \dots 1]$, i.e. the repunit continued fraction, is the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Alternative_forms).

Comment: I think, if $b \ge 4$, then that continued fraction is $\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4b}}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

In the infinite case, we have
$$[a;a,a,...] = a + \frac{1}{[a;a,a,...]}
$$
and so
$$[a;a,a,...]^2 - a [a;a,a,...] - 1 = 0
$$
Applying the quadratic formula we get
$$[a;a,a,...] = \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2+4}}{2}
$$
I suppose that's a shorthand for $[a;a,a,...]$ in some sense.

Answer (score 1):

A [*periodic continued fraction*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeriodicContinuedFraction.html) (with period $m$) is a continued fraction of the form $$\left[a_0; a_1, \dotsc, a_{n}, \overline{a_{n+1}, \dotsc, a_m}\right],$$ i.e. it is a continued fraction in which the same $m$ terms repeat indefinitely after some initial block of terms.  A periodic continued fraction with no initial block, i.e. an $m$-periodic continued faction of the form
$$ \left[ \overline{a_0; a_1, \dotsc, a_{m-1}} \right] $$
is *purely periodic continued fraction*.<sup>[1]</sup>  Therefore a continued fraction of the form
$$ \left[ a_0; \overline{a_0} \right] $$
is a *purely periodic continued fraction with period $1$*.

I am not aware of any specific terminology for terminating continued fractions in which a single term is repeated—it might be reasonable to call such a thing a *purely periodic continued fraction of length $n$*, though "periodic" tends to imply that the terms repeat infinitely often, so one would need to be very clear about the meaning of the terminology.

---

[1] I cannot find an authoritative reference for this terminology, but a [.pdf from an MIT OpenCourseware class on number theory](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec20.pdf) uses this terminology (the first occurrence is at the bottom of page 3).